# Add spacing between y-ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization, yaxis

So I am creating a multiple line but multiple y-axis ticks are overlapping each other. So is there any stacked or different approach so can view all the ticks are visible and able to plot that. Please help me if anyone has any solution. Thanks in advance.

```
from pylab import *
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline
from matplotlib.pyplot import margins
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
from matplotlib import colors

plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 300
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (35,40)
col = ['purple', 'green' , 'yellow']
position = []
position_1 = []

val = am.columns
val = val.insert(0,'Week 0')
xs = np.arange(len(val))

plt.xticks(xs, val)
plt.xticks(fontsize=35)

a = colors.to_rgb(col[0]) 
b = colors.to_rgb(col[1]) 
c = colors.to_rgb(col[2])
color = [a, b, c]
cm = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("Custom", color, N=len(am))
k = 0

frst = am['Week 1'].values
frst.sort()

color_list = [cm(i) for i in range(11)]

c_dict = dict(zip(frst, color_list))

for k in range(len(am)):
  x= np.arange(1,6)
  y = am.iloc[k].values
  colrs = c_dict[y[0]]
  position.append(y[0])
  position_1.append(y[-1] - 10)
  
  X_Y_Spline = make_interp_spline(x, y)
  
  x = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 300)
  y = X_Y_Spline(x)

  for i in range(len(x)-1):
      plt.plot(x[i:i+2], y[i:i+2], linewidth=y[i]/5, color=colrs)
      
margins(0)
plt.yticks(position, am.index.values)
plt.yticks(fontsize=35)
plt.twinx()
plt.yticks(position_1, am.index.values)
plt.yticks(fontsize=35)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what the ticks represent? It looks like they relate to horizontal lines in the background grid of the plot, but the lines are very small, and white/transparent, so hard to see. Are the y-tick labels meant to indicate which line corresponds to, e.g., 'Public Safety'? If this is the case, this is typically done with a legend, which will eliminate the problem with overlapping text.

Comment: The yticks basically represent the start of the lineplot

Comment: If their location is determined by the ends of the line plots, then I don't think there's going to be a simple way to make them not overlap. Sometimes the labels can be rotated to solve problems like this, but that wouldn't help here. I would consider a legend instead, but maybe you have reasons for not doing that. Either way, your code snippet is also incomplete. You are using a variable `am`, which is not defined in what you have provided.

Comment: am is my dataframe which I am using to plot here. I was thinking about legend but that we didn't want here. So I was thinking about stacked approach or moving in distance from grid if overlapping in order to avoid it. But don't know how to implement it.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by a 'stacked approach', nor do I know a way to vary the space from the tick to the label to ensure no overlapping text. Perhaps someone else will, but unless you share the dataframe, it's going to be impossible for anyone to test solutions.